# Stochastic Process and Probability

Tags: probability

A particle moves among $n + 1$ vertices that are situated on a circle in the following manner. At each step it moves one step either in the clockwise direction with probability $p$ or the counterclockwise direction with probability $q = 1 − p$. Starting at a specified state, call it state $0$, let $T$ be the time of the first return to state $0$. Find the probability that all states have been visited by time $T$.

I am quite confused as of to how I should start this question. Please guide me along if you know!

Thank you!

**update: so "someone" (whose uni I shall not name) tried to defame me and that person (whom I shall not name either) can't even comment now**

FINALLY COMPLETED THIS QUESTION! THANKS ALL!
CHEERS TO A BETTER COMMUNITY (:

Comment: A thought: call the vertices $0,1,2,\dots,n$.  Conditioning on the event that the first step went from 0 to 1, find the probability that a particle started at vertex 1 visits vertex n before vertex 0.  If it does then it necessarily visits all vertices before returning to 0.  Then you can do something similar in the case that the first step went from 0 to n.

Comment: I think I kinda get the idea but I honestly have no idea how I should go about doing this in steps

Comment: if you can help me out here, it'll be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding a bit on what Nate Elderedge suggested, since it's definitely the right idea:

1. Suppose the vertices are labeled from the starting point in a clockwise direction as $\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$. Consider two cases in the problem, based on where the walk's first step occurs. Specifically, if $A$ denotes the event that the walk visits all steps before returning to $0$, then $$\mathbb P_0[A] = \mathbb P_0[A \mid X_1 = 1] \cdot \mathbb P_0 [X_1 = 1] + \mathbb P_0[A \mid X_1 = n] \cdot \mathbb P_0[X_1 = n].$$
   Note that $\mathbb P_0[X_1 = 1] = p$ and $\mathbb P_0[X_1 = n] = q$, so all that remains is to compute those two conditional probabilities.
2. Use the Markov property to rewrite the conditional probabilities. Specifically, $$\mathbb P_0[A \mid X_1 = 1] = \mathbb P_1 [T_n < T_0]$$
   where $T_n$ and $T_0$ are the times of the first visits to $n$ and $0$, respectively. This expression is now a classic "gambler's ruin" problem with an asymmetric random walk. There are many solutions to this problem: see [this](http://faculty.washington.edu/fm1/394/Materials/Gambler.pdf) and [this](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/gamblers-ruin-2/) for two examples. (My favorite proof is the martingale approach, outlined in the second link -- but I'm not sure what you're already comfortable with.) You can then turn the other conditional probability into a gambler's ruin problem in the same fashion.

Comment: hmm but is there a way to put it numerically? because I actually do get your idea

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what "put it numerically" means. Can you elaborate? (My answer contains a pretty complete outline of the steps to solve the problem; are you just asking for the final answer?)

Comment: yes, you mentioned the gambler's ruin problem but I'm wondering if it's exactly the same

Comment: and yes a final answer will be useful!

Comment: It is indeed *exactly* the same as the gambler's ruin problem, as we demonstrated through the Markov property. (When I say "it," I mean the expression $\mathbb P_1[T_n < T_0]$.) Are you having trouble getting to the final answer yourself? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: ah I see I see, let me try again!